# Issue with update query in titanium alloy

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I'm new to titanium and alloy framework. I have created the models to store some data. I am able to insert and retrieve the data. I don't know How to update the row.

As suggest I did as follows,

```
var userLang = Alloy.Collections.userLanguage;   
var models = Alloy.createModel("userLanguage");
    models.fetch({id: 1});
    models.save({
       languageID: langID,
       languageText: lang
    });
```

The above code s not showing any error, But when I try to select a row from the table,

```
var userLang = Alloy.createModel('userLanguage');
 userLang.fetch({
        query: {
            statement: "SELECT * FROM userLanguage WHERE id = ?;",
            params: [ 1 ]
        }
    });
 alert("Updated value : "+userLang.get("languageText"));
```

**Model**

```
exports.definition = {
    config : {
        "columns": {
            "id": "integer",
            "languageID": "integer",
            "languageText": "text"
        },
        "adapter": {
            "type": "sql",
            "collection_name": "userLanguage"
        }
    }
};
```

The selected row is not updated as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...I need titanium query...

I guess that you are talking about Backbone. If so then below you can see an example how to update a model.

You can find more informations here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Sync_Adapters_and_Migrations

```
var model = Alloy.createModel("userLanguage");

model.fetch({id: 1});

model.save({
   languageID: langID,
   languageText: lang
});
```

Comment: The above code is not working. Can you please suggest work around. We have set the values in above the above answer right

Comment: Updated my question with original code. What's wrong with code. Please suggest some solution

Comment: Add `"idAttribute": "id"` to the "adapter" in your Model.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, But I am not able to update the row. Can you please show me an example. Please

Comment: Have you got `idAttribute` in the `adapter`?

Comment: Yeah, I have Added "idAttribute": "id" to the "adapter" in Model. It is updating one time. But from next time it is not updating. When I select the updated value I'm getting un defined value

Comment: I have tried it and it is working without any problem. Make sure that you are not getting a warning (`No config.adapter.idAttribute specified for table XXX`) also try to delete whole database (or just particular table) and start from beginning.

Comment: I have only one row in my table, I just need to update the same row and select the same. For updating and selecting I'm using the id in where condition. Can you please suggest me how can I select that row after update event happens

Answer (score 0):

to update a model you should first get it from the collection

```
var userLang = Alloy.Collections.userLanguage; 
userLang.fetch();
var langModel=userLang.get({
            id:1
     });
```

then use set to modify model's properties

```
langModel.set({
      languageText:'new value'
});
```

then save it

```
langModel.save();
```

You should not update the id if you put it as the primary key ...
You should fetch data before getting any model & after updating them  that's it.

Comment: I'm getting the following error, Uncaught TypeError Cannot call method 'set' of undefined

Comment: Edited my question by adding model

Comment: This is completely wrong. You don't have to fetch whole Collection to update only one Model. Also if you want to get a Model you can use just `get(id)`. To do `set` and then `save` is not required as well.

Comment: I'm not clear Can you please update your answer please

Comment: I tried your suggestion, But I am not able to update the row. Can you please show me an example. Please